# How to add and retrieve places on google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i am creating a app which offers a service for place to register and store general details and their location then I'd like to retrieve these places locations on the Android app ,based on the user's location, So that when a app user open the app, the registered place near that user in a 5 mile radius is listed or  shows  on map 
Kindly provide the useful solutions or links related to such scenario.
thanks

Comment: All i want to know is how to add and retrieve places  with help of google api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use markers to add locations in google maps.  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker

Answer (score 1):

Google lists everything [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map). They also have a sample app on Github [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/BasicMapDemoActivity.java). I'd suggest starting a sample map activity project in Android Studio, it should help you understand the basics of implementing a Google Map in your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
GoogleMap map = ... // get a map.
 // Add a marker at San Francisco.
 Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
     .title("San Francisco")
     .snippet("Population: 776733"));
```